# "control on" vs. "control over"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between `control on` and `control over`? Which of the below sub-sentences is correct?

> In order that the user has more control on the execution process,
>
> In order that the user has more control over the execution process,

Comment: This may be a dialect or regional issue.  To me, a native speaker of US English from New York, *control on* sounds very wrong; it is always **control over**.

Comment: @stangdon You mean to say the answer of Astralbee is wrong? Although in my context the user really does the controlling, I should write `control over`? What about `control of` in this context?

Comment: Yes, I completely disagree with Astralbee.  Saying "The user has control *on* the process" sounds completely wrong.  Saying *X has control over Y* is the normal way to say that X is doing the controlling.  *Control of* sounds good too, though!

Comment: @BA I have considerably revised my answer. I don't believe my answer was ever *wrong* as I stated that (i) both are used, and (ii) control *over* is a better choice because of the weight it carries, which is basically what your preferred answer seems to say. I'm now of the opinion that "control *on*" may be intended for something more specific and could be sometimes used incorrectly.

Comment: @Astralbee - If you can find an example of someone using "X has control on Y" correctly, I'll revise my stance as well!

Comment: @stangdon http://www.theintelligencer.net/opinion/local-columns/2014/08/kasich-has-control-on-issues/

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that this isn't a matter of "correctness", or difference in meaning, but more a matter of idiomatic speech.

I don't think *more control on* is wrong, but *over* just happens to be the preposition of choice:

[Behold the Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+control+on%2Cmore+control+over&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15). Ngrams don't always tell the whole story, but the numbers are pretty clear on this one. Note that there are indeed some instances of "more control on," so it needn't be deemed incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As with previous answers I agree **both may be used**. However you are far more likely to hear "*control **of***" rather than "on". In fact [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=control%20on%2Ccontrol%20over%2Ccontrol%20of&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontrol%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontrol%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontrol%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows that "control of" is used far more often than "control over", and "control on" is used highly infrequently.

(Note that my ngram does not includes the word *more* (ie "*more* control over*". With the word "more included" the results are quite different, with a huge spike in the use of "more control over". But all this really shows is that prior to 1970 "control" seemed to be more absolute, and since we think it comes in shades. I reckon that is due to the increase in "management speak" - saying "*we need more control over this*" is just a cleverly-spun way of saying "this is completely out of control".)

Although these may sometimes be used interchangeably I do think each carry slightly different *inferences*. In everyday speech I wouldn't give the difference much though, but if I was committing something to writing I probably would consider it more.

I would say "*control **over***" sounds more like you have some overarching control, but maybe not *actually* doing the controlling; whereas "*control **of***" sounds to me more like you are *in control*. Likewise, the apparently little used "*control **on***" doesn't specify how much involvement you have in the control process.

Consider the word "responsibility". Someone may have *responsibility **over*** something, for example a manager of a business, yet he does not carry out every task himself; but when someone has *a responsibility* or is responsible *for* a specific task it means they carry it out.

I think perhaps the use of the term "control *on*" may stem from the word "control" being used as a noun rather than a verb. For example, in the field of project management "a control" is a named process, and a control may be placed *on* something. Its use in your example may be incorrect, or idiomatic.